# Is there any way to delete the 100th row (or 'last row'), from a csv file, as a new row gets added?

Tags: python, csv, reader, writer

**Is there any way to delete the last row, from a csv file, as a new row gets added ?  *(without having to create separate / duplicate csv file)*.**

My goal is to keep the running csv file from exceeding number of rows and size.

Ideally:

1. Without creating additional file
2. Preferred csv.DictWriter/Reader , but csv.reader or csv.writer is ok.

The errors I get are:
*DictWriter is not iterable.*
And DictReader does not write to csv.

Comment: Basically you open the file for read and write and create a "DictReader" and "DictWriter" to wrap the same open file. Then you read until the last line you want to keep, and write the new line. Finally you should "truncate" the file to remove possible old data.

Comment: Thanks!   I didn't know you could open a file at same time with DictReader, THEN also DictWriter (within) the Reader loop - couldnt find example of this anywhere on web. Only alternative was to create a second file - sounded inefficient....Still reading what truncate does - seems un necessary if I do your first suggestion correctly.

Comment: If the old line was longer than the new line, the last characters of the old line will remain, therefore the "truncate". If you are sure the new line will never be shorter you can omit it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv, sys, os

filename = "sampletable2.csv"
'''
 sampletable2.csv  contains :
            high, low, precipitation
            22, 53, 0.12
            33, 52, 0.1
            44, 54, 0.1
            99, 98, 0.97 
'''
new_row = {'high': '99', 'low': '98', 'precipitation': '0.97'}
data = []  # list of dictionaries
max_rows = 4

# READER
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for i, row in enumerate(csvreader):
        if i >= max_rows:  # =row to chop - 2
            del (data[:- max_rows])  # row to chop - 2  del(data[:max_rows])  # row to chop - 2
        else:
            data.append(row)  # continually add pre found rows to new data_dic list.
    data.append(new_row)  # ALWAYS ADD ((( NEW )) FOUND SINGLE DATA RECORD
    csvfile.close()
    
    # WRITER (write while still opened for reading) ; just writes new limited row data to csv
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        fieldnames = ["high", "low", "precipitation"]
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csvwriter.writeheader()  # AWAYS WRITE HEADER due to 'w' starts all over ; never use 'a'
        csvwriter.writerows(data)
        
        f.close()  # not necess but allows to see updated csv if viewing sep monitor real-time
```

Comment: Opening the same file which is already open may produce an error or unexpected results depending on the OS. It is also unnecessary here.

Comment: So far (successfully), been looping for 12hrs every second.  Notes:  1) Maintains fixed number rows.  2) Far as I can figure, READER and WRITER must be opened at same time, same csv file, however with diff object names ('as csvfile'  then 'as newfile'). Reason is READER must be opened with 'r' since not writeable. WRITER opened with 'w' to be able to create new dict in memory, which is saved as same file.  3) Must be opened same time because (only) READER is iterable,  and WRITER is only one that can write to file. (only tested on Windows10)

Comment: Before opening the file for writing you already constructed a list "data" with the rows to write and while writing you do not iterate over the "csvreader" anymore but use only the "data" list. Therefore you could close the file for reading before opening it for writing. But if this really works this way and is only used by yourself you may keep it as it is.

Comment: Makes sense Thanks Michael  !